# relative strength index in pandas using different calculation on first row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to implement a relative strength calculation in pandas based on a .csv file with the correct calculations (below).

I've looked at previous questions on here that do something similar to how I want, but as noted there are slightly different calculations, and I can't figure out how to accomplish the one from the current CSV file. The issue that I have is that the current calculation makes use of the average of previous `up` values when the iteration number is equal to the window (yellow cells in the .csv), but subsequently makes use of previous `avg_up` values for all rows after iteration number exceeds the window (green cells in the .csv). This seems to make it circular.

Here is a screenshot of the csv with the correct implementation:
[image]

And here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [46.125,47.125,46.4375,46.9375,44.9375,44.25,
        44.625,45.75,47.8125,47.5625,47,44.5625,46.3125,
        47.6875,46.6875,45.6875,43.0625,43.5625,44.875,43.6875]
# Inputs
x = data
window = 14

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['price'])

df['delta'] = df['price'].diff()

df = df.iloc[1:]
df['up'], df['down'] = df['delta'].copy(), df['delta'].copy()
df.loc[df['delta'] < 0, 'up'] = 0
df.loc[df['delta'] > 0, 'down'] = 0
df['down'] = df['down'].abs()

df['avg_up'], df['avg_down'] = np.nan, np.nan
df['rs'], df['rsi'] = np.nan, np.nan

if df.shape[0] < window:
    print('not enough data.')
    pass
elif df.shape[0] == window:
    print("Now we calculate")
    df['avg_up'].loc[window] = df['up'].loc[-window:window].mean()
    df['avg_down'].loc[window] = df['down'].loc[-window:window].mean()
    df['rs'].loc[window] = df['avg_up'].loc[window] / df['avg_down'].loc[window]
    df['rsi'].loc[window] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df['rs'].loc[window]))
elif df.shape[0] > window:
    # Calculate the values for t=window
    df['avg_up'].loc[window] = df['up'].loc[-window:window].mean()
    df['avg_down'].loc[window] = df['down'].loc[-window:window].mean()
    df['rs'].loc[window] = df['avg_up'].loc[window] / df['avg_down'].loc[window]
    df['rsi'].loc[window] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df['rs'].loc[window]))
```

After the elif statement I now need to calculate the RSI for the rest of the data frame using the formula for only those rows after the window:

[image]

But this is where I'm having trouble. For example, when I apply the formula to the `avg_up` column it obviously overwrites the value that already exists in there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use rolling for that. You are calculating the mean from the beginning. So you need a rolling length equal data length and min_periods = window.

```
def meanf(x):
    if x.shape[0] > 14:
        res = x[:14].mean()
        for n in x[14:]:
            res = (res*(14-1)+n)/14
        return res 
    else:
        return x.mean()


df['avg_up'] = df.rolling(len(data),min_periods=window).apply(meanf)['up']
df['avg_down'] = df.rolling(len(data),min_periods=window).apply(meanf)['down']
df['rs'] = df['avg_up'] / df['avg_down']
df['rsi'] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df['rs']))
```

That should work but i cannot test it right now.

Comment: Thanks but this does not produce the correct values

Comment: The new version should work like your excel version. But you should think about just using df['avg_up'] = df.rolling(window).mean()['up']